Group (or merge) @Unroll tests from Spock in JUnit XML result file
I have a Spock @Unroll test like this:
@Unroll
def 'A session uses the TLS protocol #enabledProtocolsOfSocket #protocolOfSession'() {
    given:
    // ...

    expect:
    // ...

    where:
    enabledProtocolsOfSocket | protocolOfSession
    ["TLSv1.3"]              | "TLSv1.3"
    ["TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"]   | "TLSv1.3"
    ["TLSv1.2"]              | "TLSv1.2"
    ["TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"]   | "TLSv1.2"
    ["TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]   | "TLSv1.2"
    ["TLSv1.1"]              | "NONE"
    ["TLSv1"]                | "NONE"
    ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"]     | "NONE"
    ["TLSv1.1", "TLSv1"]     | "NONE"
}

which leads to this JUnit result XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" tests="9" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="2024-07-19T17:23:47" hostname="acme-build5eb650" time="0.403">
  <properties/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.3] TLSv1.3" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.081"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3] TLSv1.3" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.037"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.2] TLSv1.2" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.084"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1] TLSv1.2" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.07"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] TLSv1.2" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.071"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.1] NONE" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.014"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1] NONE" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.013"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1, TLSv1.1] NONE" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.013"/>
  <testcase name="A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.1, TLSv1] NONE" classname="com.acme.TlsProtocolSpec" time="0.013"/>
  <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>

The problem is: I cannot map these results to the test in post-processing the result file – there is no result named A session uses the TLS protocol #enabledProtocolsOfSocket #protocolOfSession (due to the placeholders) and there are no tests named A session uses the TLS protocol [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3] TLSv1.3 or ... or ... (due to the placeholders being replaced).
Is there some feature to "group" or "merge" these test runs into one result, named as the test? I'm thinking of something like xUnit's <collection> Element, which contains one <test> child node for each test run, like so:
<collection total="9" passed="9" failed="0" skipped="0" name="Test collection for Com.Acme.SomeClass.Tests.SomeTestName" time="0.484">
    <test name="Com.Acme.SomeClass.Tests.SomeTestName(someParam: &quot;10&quot)" ...>
    </test>
    <test name="Com.Acme.SomeClass.Tests.SomeTestName(someParam: &quot;11&quot)" ...>
    </test>
    ...
</collection>

But any solution to preserve the relation of the generically named test to all test runs (i.e. if just one test run fails, the test is reported failing) is welcome, be it by configuring the JUnit output or by some Spock feature.
Update
As @leonard-brünings pointed out: The build tool is of interest here, as it produces said output. I'm currently using Gradle 8.5 (Groovy 3.0.17, Spock 2.4-M4-groovy-4.0), configured like this:
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.required = true
        html.required = true
    }

    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I searched a bit in that direction and found settings like mergeReruns (which sounds helpful but is for failed and then retried runs?) and plugins like The Test Report Aggregation Plugin (which aggregates by type, not by testcase?) here. So at least these do not help.

Spock is not creating this output, your build tool does. However, you've omitted all pertinent information such as Spock version, Groovy/Maven version.

Thanks for pointing out! I added the details and some initial findings.

Seems that @Unroll is obsolete since Spock 2.x:

A simple @Unroll without argument is not needed anymore [...], so any simple @Unroll annotations can be removed from existing code.

But/and: There's @Rollup now, which reports a single <testcase> now, which is what I was looking for.
On the downside: Those rolled up tests do not show up individually in the IDE neither; all those #myParam1-placeholders in the test's name are obsolete now, as well (I guess).

No, @Unroll is not obsolete, it has simply become the default. I would not recommend @Rollup under normal circumstances, because unrolled tests are more advantageous. The reporting tool needs to be configured properly. Given the fact that Spock 2.x runs on top of the JUnit 5 platform, unrolled tests should be grouped automatically, just like other JUnit 5 engines like Jupiter does it for parametrised tests. Any reporting tool supporting JUnit 5 ought to be able to handle that.

Besides, I recommend a fixed name for the feature method as such and a parametrised name as an argument for @Unroll, then you have both, a common name for the feature like "TLS is a valid session protocol" and a more specific one like @Unroll('Session protocol #protocolOfSession, socket protocols #enabledProtocolsOfSocket).

"obsolete": I'm not a native speaker, sorry. Maybe "redundant" is the better term? Anyways: annotating something which already is the default is some kind of unnecessary (as Spock says in the provided link as well!). – "The reporting tool needs to be configured properly": Well, that's literally my question :-D How do I do that? – A "fixed feature name" reports 9 times "the same" test, which is no solution, while a "parameterized @Unroll name" results in the initial problem of 9 test results with a different name each.

In my comment, I just gave an example of why the annotation makes sense. See also this answer for a screenshot for how this looks in my IDE and should look like in a test report.

Thank you. Yes, my IntelliJ dispalys this the same. But in the XML it's as I described. That's what I meant in my answer: While @Rollup fixes my problem (in the XML!) it has a downside in the IDE's display (which was not the scope of my question, though)

Which confirms my opinion that @Rollup is just a workaround with a bad trade-off, by no means a solution.
